# Map Routing (paper route)

Tags: raster, network, route, mapping

I am doing a undergraduate GIS project. It entails a paper route for newspapers in the Pittsburgh Area, so far I have plotted all of the points in a point layer. I have now plotted my points, what should be my next steps? I downloaded basemaps of the roads, and the data set for the pgh roads. I want to: find the shortest distance (elucian distance), I need to start a new network data set from what? (how)?

Please suggest anything else that would be useful or make this project better. Or a list or steps necessary for completing the project.

Comment: What software are you using? Is this a vehicular or pedestrian (bike) route? You probably won't be looking at Euclidean distance, since that doesn't take into account the network (road) constraints - it's 'as the crow flies'. If using ArcGIS you'll need the Network Analyst extension, and there are some [tutorials provided](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00470000005r000000) that would help get you started. I will note that depending on your source, getting a clean/network analysis ready dataset may be the bulk of your work compared to actually solving for a route.